# ? preceding token is not quantifiable

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got this regex which doesn't give any problems in the chrome browser but that crashes the storybook on safari with this error:

> Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name

When I put my regex in the regex101.com editor, it gave me no errors (in the PHP section) but when I switched it to javascript i got this error:

> ? The preceding token is not quantifiable

regex: `/^(.*)(?<=(@))([^@ ])*(<br>)?$/`

I don't know what's wrong with it and why it crashes on safari but it doesn't crash my chrome storybook

Comment: The positive lookbehind `(?<=` is not fully supported, it is in Chrome. Can you add to the question what you want to match?

Comment: Well that's just it, that pattern is an example, I made a regex that takes in delimiters as parameters and makes a form of that regex to match various inputs to filter a list of strings (it's some sort of autocomplete use case with different lists for different delimiters) the all round regex looks like this:

new RegExp(`^(.*)(?<=(${leftDelimiter}))([^${leftDelimiter}${rightDelimiter || ''} ])*(<br>)?$`, 'gm');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditional JavaScript doesn't support look-behind assertions (`(?<=...)`) in regexes. Apparently Chrome has started implementing them, but most other browsers have not.

However, I don't see why you need look-behind at all here:

```
/^(.*(@))([^@ ])*(<br>)?$/
```

seems like it should achieve the same thing.

Comment: you're absolutely right, it does achieve the same thing, thanks!